# Better ways to filter based on an optional conditional

Tags: java, option-type

Say I have an optional of type `Optional<T>` and of operation which returns an `Optional<Boolean>` from input `T`.

```
final Optional<T> opt = ...
final Optional<Boolean> condition = opt.flatMap(this::someOperation);
```

I wanted to filter `opt` for `condition` being both present and true. I could write the following, but it seems kind of bulky:

```
opt.filter(t -> someOperation(t).orElse(false))
```

Maybe that's already concise enough, but I thought it would be nice to have something like bellow:

```
opt.flatFilter(this::someOperation)
```

Comment: I think your solution reads quite fine. I think any other "genius" solutions would be quite unintuitive. I did a couple of tries, but couldn't find anything better.

Comment: @marstran yeah; I guess I might be overthinking this :p

Comment: I would rethink `someOperation` returning `Optional<Boolean>`. That's basically just a tri-state. Is there a better way to represent that information, maybe an `enum`?

Comment: @StuartMarks In my situation I'm calling a method which may fail to retrieve data, otherwise it grabs a boolean value. I thought it was an appropriate choice; but I'm open to suggestion!

Comment: The semantics of using `Optional` this way strike me as odd, but they might work for your application. To me, an empty `Optional` indicates the absence of a value. If the request to retrieve data failed, it might be that there is a value there, and retrying would actually succeed at retrieving it. Then again, these cases might be the same for your application. If so, maybe have `someOperation` return a `boolean` instead of `Optional<Boolean>`.